# Unrelated Business Taxable Income (UBTI) exceeding limit in IRA

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, ira, roth-ira

I've kept an MLP stock in an IRA for several years not wanting to deal with the K-1 tax complexities.  However it looks like this year my Unrelated Business Taxable Income (UBTI) will exceed the $1000 limit.  I've talked with my IRA custodian (Schwab) and have uploaded my K-1 which apparently they will process and pay the IRS using funds from my IRA account on form 990-T, I believe.  Schwab probably won't get a chance to process my K-1 before the April 18th deadline and wouldn't provide advice if I should wait to file my personal income taxes before they process my 990-T.

My question is, do I need to wait to hear back from Schwab (likely requesting an extension past April 18th) before submitting my personal federal income taxes?  I'd rather not request an extension, but I DEFINATELY don't want to have to file an amended return.  In other words, is there anywhere on my federal return where I need to enter the 'results' of Schwab's completed 990-T?  Because it sounds like I can submit my federal income taxes separately along with any other money I owe, and meanwhile if it turns out I owe UBTI in the IRA then Schwab will pay the IRS for me using funds from my IRA.

Comment: https://www.ubs.com/us/en/wealth-management/who-we-serve/individuals-and-families/ira-rollover/_jcr_content/mainpar/toplevelgrid_1676368978/col1/linklist_180342600/link.1348489289.file/PS9jb250ZW50L2RhbS9hc3NldHMvd21hL3VzL3NoYXJlZC9kb2N1bWVudHMvZmFxLXVidGkucGRm/faq-ubti.pdf

Comment: Q23: Does the filing of the Form 990-T return impact an individual's personal tax return?
A23: No. The IRA will be assigned its own Employer Identification Number (EIN) for the filing of the Form
990-T. This EIN separates the IRA trust from the owner’s Social Security Number, which is used in the
individual tax return. The Form 990-T is a separately filed return, though due at the same time, and
should not be combined with an IRA owner’s individual return

Comment: Above question/answer from above link seems to suggest I do not have to wait to file my personal return